# How to get value from nested dictionary?

Tags: python

I have information below:

```
zipcode = {"country_1": 
               {"city_1": 100, 
                "city_2": 103, 
                "city_3": 104},
           "country_2": 
               {"city_4": 208, 
                "city_5": 220, 
                "city_6": 221}
           }
```

How to write three functions that :

- If I input `country_1`, it will print all the `zipcode` of the cities in that country?
- And if I input any `city`, it will print the corresponding `zipcode`
- And vice versa( input `zipcode`, return `city`)

Answer (score 1):

> If I input country_1, it will print all the zipcode of the cities in that country?

```
>>> zipcode = {'country_1': {'city_2': 103, 'city_3': 104, 'city_1': 100}, 'country_2': {'city_4': 208, 'city_6': 221, 'city_5': 220}}
>>> c = "country_1"; list(zipcode[c].values())
[103, 104, 100]
```

> And if I input any city, it will print the corresponding zipcode

```
>>> c = "city_1"; [d[c] for d in zipcode.values() if d.get(c)]
[100]
```

I left the output here as a list because there are many cities share names with cities in other countries.  (For example, `Syracuse` or `Rome`.)  So, this allows for the possibility that more than one zipcode will be found.

> and vice versa?

```
>>> z=100; [k for d in zipcode.values() for k in d if d.get(k)==z]
['city_1']
```

For the latter, you might want to know which country `city_1` was in.  In that case:

```
>>> z=100; ["{}, {}".format(k, c) for c, d in zipcode.items() for k in d if d.get(k)==z]
['city_1, country_1']
```

#### Addendum

The following code, from the comments, has issues:

```
z=input('please enter zipcode:')
print( [zipcode.keys() for zipcode.keys() in zipcode for zipcode in zipcode.values() if zipcode.get()==z] )
```

Let's start with the first line:

```
>>> z=input('please enter zipcode:')
please enter zipcode:100
```

Now, let's display `z` to see what we have:

```
>>> z
'100'
```

As you can see, `z` is a string.  Looking above, though, one can see that the zip codes in the variable `zipcode` are integers.  We will have to make `z` an integer before we match it to anything in `zipcode`.  The following uses the `int` function to do that:

```
>>> z=int(input('please enter zipcode:'))
please enter zipcode:100
>>> z
100
```

As for the second line, `zipcode.keys()` is a function call but it is used in a place where a variable is required.  Likewise, `for zipcode in zipcode.values()` treats `zipcode` as two different things.  Fixing those issues yields:

```
>>> print( [city for country in zipcode.values() for city in country if country.get(city)==z] )
['city_1']
```

Comment: Thanks! I edit the cities in country_2 to 4, 5, and 6.

Comment: @EricChen I have updated the answer for the new input data.

Comment: Hi, can you shed more light on part 3 ( input zip code then return value)? What does k stand for? Thank you!

Comment: `d` is the dictionary for a country.  `k` is a city in that country.  (I called it `k` because cictionaries have "keys" and "values" and the cities are the "keys" in the country dictionary.)  So, for example, `d.get(k)` gets the zip code for city `k` in country dictionary `d`.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I write the code based on your example but can not figure out where is wrong: z=input('please enter zipcode:'), print( [zipcode.keys() for zipcode.keys() in zipcode for zipcode in zipcode.values() if zipcode.get()==z]

Comment: @EricChen I added a section to the answer to discuss the issues with those two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You want one function which does both? It may not be the best idea! This does what you want:

```
zipcode = {"country_1": {"city_1": 100, "city_2": 103, "city_3": 104},"country_2": {"city_1": 208, "city_2": 220, "city_3": 221}}

def get_zipcode(word):
    if word in zipcode:
        return zipcode[word].values()

    for data in zipcode.values():
        if word in data:
            return data[word]

    return None
```

Comment: Thanks! And how to insert the input function in it?

Comment: @EricChen Like `get_zipcode('country_1')` or `get_zipcode('city_2')`?

Comment: Hi, I want to know how to use the input function => word=input('please type country name:')  in the suite

Comment: `word = raw_input('Please type a country or city name: ')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, a bit tricky, but it does what (all the 3 in 1) you asking for :) 
assuming each country name, city name, and zip code is unique, `get_value()` will return the corresponding value to its input.

By country name:

```
>>> get_value('country_1', zipcode)
[103, 104, 100]
```

Or by city name:

```
>>> get_value('city_3', zipcode)
104
```

Or by a zipcode:

```
>>> get_value('100', zipcode)
'city_1'
```

zipcode should be your nested dictionary:

```
def get_value(c, zipcode):

    if c in zipcode.keys():
        return zipcode[c].values()
    else:
        for d in zipcode.values():
            for k, v in d.iteritems():
                if c == k:
                    return d[k]
                try:
                    int(c) == v
                    return k
                except ValueError:
                    continue
    return None
```

Comment: Thank you! I should mention that I want to write three functions to execute the request respectively.